# How get list of "model with data" from SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, mvvm

Hey i have code like that

It returns list of Model from reader. How can i do it better? Dont use this

```
address.Add(new Address {
    ID = (int) reader["ID"],
    Address = reader["Address"].ToString(),
    PhoneNumber = (int) reader["PhoneNumber"]
});
```

But use more like this `address.Add(new Address(reader?or somthing else));`, or maybe if i can dont use List and return data where only in class where it return i can add to observable collection??

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Address>> LoadDetail(int id)
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        List<Address> address = new List<Address>();
        using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM Address WHERE ID = {id}";,
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    address.Add(new Address { ID = (int)reader["ID"], Address = reader["Address"].ToString(), PhoneNumber = (int)reader["PhoneNumber"] });
                }
            }
        }
        return address;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If async code is not a necessity you can avoid creating a list and write this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    yield return new Address { ID = (int)reader["ID"], Address = reader["Address"].ToString(), PhoneNumber = (int)reader["PhoneNumber"] };
}
```

You can improve it with extension method for the reader:

```
yield return reader.GetAddress();

public static class ReaderExtensions
{
    public static Address GetAddress(this SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        return new Address { ID = (int)reader["ID"], Address = reader["Address"].ToString(), PhoneNumber = (int)reader["PhoneNumber"] };
    {
}
```